Right way to create synchronous provider which depends on Async Provider and watch it using riverpod
I have two providers such that one fetches users from cloud firestore and another provider which get unique ID (UID) for that user. A number of functions and widgets depend on the UID.
Riverpod won't allow to watch the UID provider without a final keyword on my variable.
What I am trying to achieve is get client name from a dropdownMenu. Find corresponding UID and use it to draw other widgets and perform some functions.
Please suggest what should be the correct way?
class _CreateJobState extends ConsumerState<CreateJob> {
late String chosenClientUid;

  @override
  void initState() {
  clientController = TextEditingController();
  clientController?.addListener(_runFindClientUid);
  chosenClientUid = ref.watch(chosenClientUidProvider); // Watching my UID provider which is not correct and IDE shows error
  super.initState();
  }

  void _runFindClientUid() {
    /*.... Setting chosenClientUid here ...*/
    final String chosenClient = clientController!.text;
    ref.read(chosenClientUidProvider.notifier).setChosenClientUid(chosenClient);
  }

  void _someOperationFunction() async {
    /*.... Use chosenClientUid here also for some other operation...*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DropDownMenu(
          controller: clientController,
          /*...getting clients using fetchClientsProvider, so this widget is another ConsumerStatefulWidget. Combined here to shorten the code...*/
          dropdownMenuEntries: 
          // Client Name selected here
          onSelected: (Object? client) {
            setState(() {
              if (client != null) widget.clientNameController.text = client.toString();
            });
          },
        ),
        // ... Build OtherWidgets based not the value of chosenClientUid
      ]
    )
  }
}

Riverpod Providers are
@riverpod
class ChosenClientUid extends _$ChosenClientUid {
  @override
  String? build() {
    return '';
  }

  void setChosenClientUid(String clientName) {
    final AsyncValue<List<User>> clients = ref.watch(fetchClientsProvider);
    String uid = '';
    if(clients.value != null && clients.hasValue) {
      if(clients.value!.length > 0) {
        for (var clt in clients.value!) {
          if (clt.name == clientName) {
            uid = clt.uid;
            state = uid;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@riverpod
Future<List<User>> fetchClients(FetchClientsRef ref) async {
  List<User> _clientList = [];
  final clientDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .get();
  for (var client in clientDataSnapshot.docs) {
    _clientList.add(User.fromMap(client));
  }
  return _clientList;
}


ref.watch(chosenClientUidProvider) can not be used in initState(), it is used inside the build fn in widget
so write this line in  chosenClientUid = ref.watch(chosenClientUidProvider); inside build fn then only it will rebuild the widget

OK, then pass this variable from build function to all other functions and widgets to update them automatically? Or watch them separately everywhere? All the functions are in the same StatefulWidget!

pass this to all other fn, when the parent widget rebuild the child widget will also rebuild.
I can't find where you are calling other fn, so if these other fn you are talking about is not called in build fn, you need to use watch with setState to rebuild the widget.
(Like if the other fn are called on click events or other events, you can use read to get value and call setState to reflect changes.)
It will be great if you can give more code to understand this.

It all depends on use case most of time watch is only used inside build method() or inside other providers. It is not a norm to use watch inside fn that are defined inside a widget but are not called inside build method, for that we use read like form above example when some action or event is performed.
In your case when the item from dropdown is clicked, you can read() the value and call set state to rebuild widget.

Thanks for the concepts, I'll try this out. I have posted less code to make it easier, it is actually a form consisting of Drop downs and TextFormFields and some custom calendar type widget having 1000+  lines of code. To break it into smaller problem, based on client I have chosen I want to rebuild another dropdownMenu's entries and if client does not already exist, show Animated Container to add details of new client.
